# Primefaces file upload UI issue per table row

Tags: jsf-2.2

I have a Primefaces 5.1 tabular UI on front-end.

Each row has upload button.

When browsed and selected file at a particular row, the upload button becomes active at the last row. 
It needs to be active where the file is browsed and selected.
There seems to be a javascript bug while using the file uploader combined with tabular UI.
The upload button works(other than its UI at a different row) and the file is uploaded to the right row(the row that the file was browsed previously).

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{datas.attach_doc_ids==null}">
   <p:growl id="uploadMSG" showDetail="true"/>
   <p:fileUpload 
      previewWidth="0"
      process="data_tab"
      id="file_upper"
      styleClass="fileUploadStyle"
      onstart="showloader();"
      oncomplete="hideloader();"
      auto="false"
      mode="advanced"
      label=""
      dragDropSupport="false"
      widgetVar="fileUploader"
      fileUploadListener="#{datasBean.submitUploadedFile}"
      allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|doc|docx|doc)$/"
      onerror="console.log('bad file type!');"
      update="uploadMSG"/>

<script>
   registerRowClickForFileUpload(#{indexvar});
</script>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Would you know what might be causing this?

Also the datatable definition below:

```
styleClass="wr_datatable"
                id="data_tab"
                paginatorPosition="bottom"
                var="datas"
                value="#{datasBean.listDatas}"
                widgetVar="dataTable"
                emptyMessage="No data found. Please change the search criteria above."
                paginator="true"
                selection="#{datasBean.selectedData}"
                rowKey="#{datas.data_pk}"
                selectionMode="single"
                rowIndexVar="indexvar"
                draggableColumns="true"
                resizableColumns="true"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}
                {FirstPageLink}
                {PreviousPageLink}
                {PageLinks}
                {NextPageLink}
                {LastPageLink}
                {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rows="10"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20"
```

Datatable:

```
        <p:column headerText="Status" width="150"
                  sortBy="#{datas.data_status}">

            <p:selectOneMenu  value="#{datas.data_status}" onchange="selectme(#{indexvar});">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="0" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="1" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="2" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="3" >
                <f:selectItem itemValue="5" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="4" />

                <p:ajax event="change"
                        async="true"
                        process="@form"
                        global="true"
                        update="data_tab"
                        listener="#{datasBean.updatedataStatus}">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{datas}"
                                                 target="#{datasBean.selecteddata}"/>
                </p:ajax>
            </p:selectOneMenu>

        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText=“name” sortBy="#{datas.name}" ><h:outputText value="#{datas.name}"/></p:column>
        <p:column headerText=“dob"><h:outputText value="#{datas.date_of_birth}"/></p:column>
        <p:column headerText=“number” sortBy="#{datas.number}" ><h:outputText value="#{datas.number}”/></p:column>
        <p:column headerText=“date” sortBy="#{datas.data_datetime}"><h:outputText value="#{datas.data_datetime}"/></p:column>
        <p:column headerText=“second name“ sortBy="#{datas.second_name}”>
            <h:outputText value="#{datas.second_name}”/>
        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Institution" sortBy="#{datas.institution}">
            <h:outputText value="#{datas.institution}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Documents" >

                                <p:graphicImage library="images"
                            name="attach-doc-exist.png"
                            title="Open Attachement Document"
                            onclick="selectme(#{indexvar});
                                    openDocJS(‘ATTACHEMET_DOCUMENT');" 
                            rendered="#{datas.attach_doc_ids!=null}"/>
            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{datas.attach_doc_ids==null}">
                <p:growl id="uploadMSG" showDetail="true"/>
                <p:fileUpload 
                    previewWidth="0"
                    process="data_tab"
                    id="file_upper"
                    styleClass="fileUploadStyle"
                    onstart="showloader();"
                    oncomplete="hideloader();"
                    auto="false"
                    mode="advanced"
                    label=""
                    dragDropSupport="false"
                    widgetVar="fileUploader"
                    fileUploadListener="#{datasBean.submitUploadedFile}"
                    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|doc|docx|doc)$/"
                    onerror="console.log('bad file type!');"
                    update="uploadMSG"/>

                <script>
                    registerRowClickForFileUpload(#{indexvar});

                </script>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <p:remoteCommand name="openMedicalReport"
                             global="true"
                             async="true"
                             actionListener="#{datasBean.manageReport}"/>

            <p:remoteCommand name="lockFile"
                             global="true"
                             async="true"
                             actionListener="#{datasBean.manageFilePermission}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="MOD" width="30">

            <h:outputText value="#{datas.data_mods}"/>
        </p:column>


        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" async="true" global="false">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{datasBean.selecteddata}" value="#{datas}" />
        </p:ajax>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: this panelGroup represents the last column right?

Comment: if so, this markup shouldn't even render on the server side. You're using non-dynamic id and widgetVar values on something that represents multiple rows. That doesn't make sense. Could you share your whole data table definition? I don't know what you mean by tabular UI. is it a datatable?

Comment: just added the data table definition as well.

Comment: it does not change the ui-state disabled and disabled=disabled in the right row... it always changes it at the very last row...
I know I can write some javascipt code to overcome this but is there a way to solve it using Primefaces? Or am I doing something wrong with my definitions and there is a conflict somewhere? Thanks

Comment: those are just attributes of the datatable. we'll need the whole datatable markup.

Comment: Added the datatable as well. Thank you.

Comment: The value of the widgetVar must be unique. It is not prepended with anything the namingcontainer or appended with an index. You have to do that yourself

Comment: Please take a look at my second comment. not just widgetVar, all id fields must contain a dynamic value. if you're not accessing them by their ids, delete the id attributes. if you are, then add row id to the ids and change the code that accesses those components

Comment: Yes it is fixed! Thank you so much. I knew the references were causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced the widgetVar with a dynamically generated value to get unique file upload widget which fixed the issue as suggested by the comments above :)

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{datas.attach_doc_ids==null}">
   <p:growl id="uploadMSG" showDetail="true"/>
   <p:fileUpload 
      previewWidth="0"
      process="data_tab"
      id="file_upper"
      styleClass="fileUploadStyle"
      onstart="showloader();"
      oncomplete="hideloader();"
      auto="false"
      mode="advanced"
      label=""
      dragDropSupport="false"
      widgetVar="#{datas.data_pk}"
      fileUploadListener="#{datasBean.submitUploadedFile}"
      allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|doc|docx|doc)$/"
      onerror="console.log('bad file type!');"
      update="uploadMSG"/>

<script>
   registerRowClickForFileUpload(#{indexvar});
</script>
</h:panelGroup>
```